# lumia 720 after Windows Phone 8.1 update

Tags: lumia

I am facing below problems after upgrading to 8.1

1. Phone automatically restarts when I lock my phone.
2. I could see incoming call but unable to receive it. The touch screen doesn't work at this time.

Comment: Which build have you got installed?

Comment: It's 8.10.12382.878

Comment: Those two look like separate issues, so please post them as separate questions.

Comment: That's not the latest version of 8.1, so update first  (.895 is the latest version), also try resetting the phone?

Comment: I am also facing this screen freeze issue. My Lumia version is 8.10.12393.0. Soft restart option solves this at that time.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: long press the lock button ........should be restart the phone try it.

Answer (score 2):

Well these problems are likely to happen in the Developer Preview. I myself have a Lumia 720 and the phone used to restart itself when at times I used WhatsApp. But in the build version 8.10.12398.895, I don't have face these problems anymore. I recommend you update your phone to the latest version. If this doesn't fix your problem, try resetting your phone, but before this do make a backup of your files. The Lumia Cyan update is just around the corner, the Lumia Cyan is the firmware update by Nokia that brings new features and also optimizes your phone for Windows Phone 8.1 and is the official update. The Lumia Cyan is expected to fix all such problems.